# ¿Qué es mejor usar --link o network?

Tags: docker

Llevo con docker solo dos semanas, soy bastante novata.He leído en algunos artículos y en la propia pagina de Docker que los enlaces entre contenedores están obsoletos, que la recomendación es usar network. La información que encuentro sobre network es algo escasa y creando un nuevo network y conectando a dicho network los dos contenedores que necesito conectar, me da error el contenedor de wordpress:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in Standard input code on line 22
>   2018-08-01T15:58:15.046526300Z

Los dos contenedores que uso son mysql y wordpress.
¿Alguien me podría hechar una mano con mis dudas entre usar link o network y las diferencias que hay entre ellas?

Se me olvidó decir, que yo empleo Dockerfile, no docker-compose.

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

P.D.: He descubierto ya el error de donde viene, por si alguien necesita saberlo. Las variables que comparten los contenedores no concordaban, es decir, algunas variables ,por error ,estaban mal escritas y la variable wordpress_db_host del contenedor worpress apuntaba mal.

Comment: La propiedad link esta obsoleta aunque puede usarse todavia. Te recomiendo que te pases a la versión 3.*. Echa un ojo a este articulo: [Descripción del fichero docker-compose.yml](https://pedrojimenez.info/docker/compose-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link es una feature obsoleta que ya no se debe usar, es reemplazada por networks.

Una bridge network, permite que dos contenedores se descubran siempre y cuando pertenecan a la misma bridge network y aislarlos del resto de los contenedores.

Si usas dos contenedores que deben interactuar juntos, lo mejor es que crees un docker-compose.yml.

Para crearlos es muy sencillo.

```
version: '3'
services:

  wordpres:
    image: wordpress:latest
    networks:
      -  my_net

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    networks:
      - my_net

networks:
  my_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Si no quieres usar un docker-compose debes crear la red primero

`docker network create NAME`

y luego al hacer docker run de tus imágenes especificar la red

`docker run wordpress --network NAME`

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación, ahora lo tengo más claro. Entonces una pregunta, es necesario crear la network antes de hacer el run? No se puede conectar después los contenedores? Y otra pregunta más, y perdón por preguntar tanto, si esta obsoleto link porque aparece como opción cuando haces network help, es la el mismo link o es otro tipo?

Comment: Generalmente es más cómodo crear todo junto en un compose. 
No necesariamente otros contenedor puede conectarse a una red, depende el tipo de red. Con respecto a porque sigue estando la opcion link, supongo por retrocompatibilidad, pero en cada nueva version a demas de agregar cosas tambien las sacan. Quedan como deprecadas un par de versiones y luego las sacan.